# Algorithm to sort image data

Tags: matlab, image-processing, sobel, canny-operator

I'm trying to find the distance between some columns in a picture, in order to determine the distance the picture was taken from. Here is my code:

```
I = rgb2gray(imread('vlc1.png'));
im = edge(I,'sobel', 'vertical'); %Can also use canny
c1=sum(im>0);
plot(c1)
p=c1>40;
k=find(p)
```

The picture im using:

[image]

I'm finding all the white pixels in each of the columns of the image and then finding all the values above a threshold (40 right now).

I would then like to find the distance in pixels between the peaks in c1 so i can use this formula:

```
distance to object = focal length * real height of the object * image height / (object height * sensor height)
```

So I need an algorithm that can find the object height in pixels, with the height being the distance between the columns you can see in the picture.

Comment: Maybe you could mark on the picture in red the thing you want to meaaure.

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with sorting...